# 15 days of Sql From hackerrank

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am unable to understand the use of this line in a code can someone please explain me about this or give some different way to approach to this question

Link to the question:https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/15-days-of-learning-sql

Code:

```
select 
    submission_date ,    
    (    SELECT COUNT(distinct hacker_id)  
         FROM Submissions s2  
         WHERE s2.submission_date = s1.submission_date 
               AND (  SELECT COUNT(distinct s3.submission_date) 
                         FROM      Submissions s3 
                         WHERE 
                           s3.hacker_id = s2.hacker_id 
                           AND s3.submission_date < s1.submission_date
                   ) = dateDIFF(s1.submission_date , '2016-03-01')) 
    , (   select hacker_id  
          from submissions s2 
          where s2.submission_date = s1.submission_date 
          group by hacker_id 
         order by count(submission_id) desc , hacker_id limit 1
       ) as shit
    ,  (   select name 
           from hackers where hacker_id = shit
       )
FROM  
(    select distinct submission_date 
     from submissions) s1
group by submission_date
```

Unable to understand why they have used this line from this part of the code:

```
 (s3.submission_date < s1.submission_date) = dateDIFF(s1.submission_date , '2016-03-01'))
```

Comment: That's *not* the entire line. It's `(SELECT COUNT(distinct s3.submission_date) FROM      Submissions s3 WHERE s3.hacker_id = s2.hacker_id AND s3.submission_date < s1.submission_date) = datediff ...`  It compares the result of a subquery with the days between `submission_date` and `'2016-03-01`. It's also a very ugly query that results in awful performance

Comment: Downvoters, did **YOU** understand this ... before I edited it? With proper indentation to show the glory of multiple grouping queries are performed for each column? Do you understand what it does *NOW*? The middle column name is apt.

Comment: On the other hand, MySQL doesn't have the Standard SQL windowing, ranking functions that make calculating running sums, counts and ranking easy. SQL Server does, but can't handle date windows. Even with MySQL though, it's possible to write a far better query than this

Comment: Can you just give an example query for the above code

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #max_submissions (
    submission_date date,
    hacker_id integer,
    submission_count integer,
    ordering_row integer
)

insert into #max_submissions 
select 
    submission_date, 
    hacker_id, 
    submission_count, 
    row_number() over(partition by submission_date order by submission_count desc, hacker_id) as ordering_row
from (
    select submission_date, 
            hacker_id,
            count(hacker_id) as submission_count
    from submissions
    group by submission_date, hacker_id
) tbl_submission_count 

CREATE TABLE #hacker_counts (
    submission_date date,
    hacker_count integer
)

insert into #hacker_counts
select tbl.submission_date, 
        COUNT(distinct tbl.hacker_id) as cc 
from (
    select *,
            (case when (
                            (select count(*) 
                                from (select distinct * 
                                        from (select s1.hacker_id, 
                                                    s1.submission_date 
                                                from Submissions s1 
                                                where s1.hacker_id = s.hacker_id and
                                                (s1.submission_date >= '2016-03-01' and 
                                                s1.submission_date <= s.submission_date)) t1 
                                    ) t2 
                            ) >= (DATEDIFF(day, '2016-03-01', s.submission_date) + 1) )
                    then 1
                    else 0
            end) as logic
    from Submissions s
) tbl
where tbl.logic = 1
group by tbl.submission_date



select max_submissions.submission_date, 
    hacker_counts.hacker_count, 
    max_submissions.hacker_id, 
    h.name 
from #max_submissions max_submissions
inner join hackers h on max_submissions.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
left join #hacker_counts hacker_counts on max_submissions.submission_date = hacker_counts.submission_date
where max_submissions.ordering_row = 1
order by max_submissions.submission_date

drop table #max_submissions
drop table #hacker_counts
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand this line

```
(  SELECT COUNT(distinct s3.submission_date) 
          FROM      Submissions s3 
          WHERE 
          s3.hacker_id = s2.hacker_id 
          AND s3.submission_date < s1.submission_date)
                  = dateDIFF(s1.submission_date , '2016-03-01')
```

**First understand left hand side:**

```
(SELECT COUNT(distinct s3.submission_date) FROM Submissions s3 WHERE s3.hacker_id = s2.hacker_id AND s3.submission_date < s1.submission_date)
```

This line counts the unique submission dates for each hacker_id uptil the current date,
So if the date for one row is `2016-03-05`, it will count unique submissions for a hacker_id uptil this date (note it will  count multiple submissions by a single hacker on a day as 1 count only)

In other words, this takes a hacker_id and start checking if there is a submission by this hacker_id for each day from 1st day uptil this day,it will do this for each submission date

**Then Understand Right Hand Side:**
`dateDIFF(s1.submission_date , '2016-03-01')`
this  will take the difference of this current date `2016-03-05` to first day `2016-03-01`,

**Understanding the whole statement now:**

So if a hacker made at least one submission each day from `2016-03-05` to `2016-03-01`, then both sides of the above code will be equal,
that is date difference from 5th to 1st will be 5 (Right Hand Side) and distinct submission date for a hacker who made at least one submission each day from 1st to 5th will also be 5 (left hand side)